# accessing jQuery ajax response object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please i am trying to read a response form my ajax request from alphavantage

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  alert("hey");
  const urlToFetch = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&outputsize=full&apikey=demo';

  function getData() {

    $.ajax({
      url: urlToFetch,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',

      success(response) {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error(jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
      }
    });
  }
  getData();

});
```

Comment: I was successful in pulling the data down, but i am not to familiar with parsing json data especially from an api response object. any suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: Your question isn't about ajax, it's about how to access members of an object. Asked and answered lots of times. Also: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/9aybwcry/

Comment: so whats the right question to ask? and how do i access members of this object?

Comment: Did you check the browser's console and look at the structure of the object? You can access members using dot or bracket notation. For instance `response["Meta Data"]` will give you the first part. `response["Meta Data"]["3. Last Refreshed"]` will give the date. And so on. You could also have googled for "js how to access members of an object"

Comment: yes i checked the browsers console, but i am confused on what the right keywords are, if you can just share a link to a documenter a video that'll help me understand this concept i would appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. Will this help? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/eLjb1tag/

Answer (score 0):

When you're getting JSON from your ajax, in your example, on success, use `JSON.parse(response)`, then the response will become a javascript object. You can then do whatever you need with that object.

Comment: It's already a JS object, the OP is asking how to access its contents.

Comment: OP commented that he/she is "not to familiar with parsing json data especially from an api response object"...JSON.parse will parse the response into a javascript object. To access a javascript object's contents, here's a beginner's guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics

Comment: In this concrete example, which uses `dataType: 'json'`, the argument passed to the `success` function is already parsed. OP is asking about "read[ing] a response", i.e. accessing the data in the object. They call it "parsing" but are referring to accessing the object's members.

Comment: okay wait, so the json response is not accessible if it isn't parsed into a js object.